# How to log all Cognito User details in API Gateway Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to understand what are the available claims I am able to access from the API Gateway when an user makes an authenticated request.

The API Gateway Mapping Template Reference (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) is listing different authorizer claims but it looks like only "sub" and "email" work.

All the other claims are logged as "-"

I'm logging the requests with CloudWatch, as described in this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html

I would like to get the username too but none of the following mapping work:

- $context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']
- $context.authorizer.claims\['cognito:username'\]
- $context.identity.cognitoIdentityId

Answer (score 1):

The question is very old but I'd like to add that configuring the log format like this does work now, using the `['cognito:username']`of the original author of this question.

```
{"cognitoUsername":"$context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']","httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod"}
```

Probably something AWS fixed in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

To see a list of all available properties you can temporarily add this to your mapping template: `$context.authorizer.claims.keySet()`.